# Looping through multiple if_else statements

Tags: r

I have a df that has several columns including one column with a range of values from 0 to around 100:

```
> df$days_fract
```

`1] 0.000000000 0.006944444 0.013888889 0.020833333 0.027777778 0.034722222`

Based on the value, I want to loop through multiple if-statements to create a new column which contains a string labelling the cycle number:

```
df$cycle <- ifelse(df$days_fract < 0.5 , "cycle0",
 ifelse(df$days_fract >= 0.5 & df$days_fract < 1.5 , "cycle1",
  ifelse(df$days_fract >= 1.5 & df$days_fract < 2.5 , "cycle2",
   ifelse(df$days_fract >= 2.5 & df$days_fract < 3.5 , "cycle3",
    ifelse(df$days_fract >= 3.5 & df$days_fract < 4.5 , "cycle4",NA)))))
```

However, since df$days_fract is quite long, this isn't very handy at all. Basically, I want to loop through it somehow (or other ideas very welcome) where each cycle ranges from 1.5-2.5, 2.5-3.5, 3.5-4.5 and so on.

Comment: Maybe you can try `df$cycle <- paste0("cycle",floor((df$days_fract%/%0.5+1)/2)-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple ifelse statements, an option is `cut`

```
with(df, cut(days_fract, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5),
       labels = paste0("cycle", 0:4)))
```